# check for particular value in an array

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a dropdown and fetched the option tag values in an array. I want to check whether the textbox value matches with array value.

HTML:

```
<select>
<option>test1</option>
<option>test2</option>
<option>test3</option>
<option>test4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txt" /> //textbox
<input class="bt" type="button" id="btntest" value="Check for the Value">
```

I got the **array** using the following Jquery:

```
var values = $('select').children('option').map(function (i, e) 
{
return e.innerText;
});
```

Now **values** variable  holds the result as **test1,test2,test3,test4**

Question: If user typed "**test2**" in textbox(**txt**), How to check whether **test2** is available in the array and so on. If user entered anything apart from array values should display an error message.

Please find the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ismailvtl/9LAab/4/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/9LAab/7/)

```
$('#btntest').click(function () {
   if ($.inArray($('#txt').val(), values) > -1) {
      console.log("available");
   }else{
     console.log("not available");
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle adil

Comment: When I chose the first item from the list it says "not Available"

Comment: make sure you have `> -1` in if condition

Answer (score 2):

There is a inbuilt jquery function inArray
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

```
jQuery.inArray("test2", values)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery [InArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
jQuery.inArray( $('#txt').val() , values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`jQuery.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

```
if( jQuery.inArray( yourValue, yourArray) ){ //doStuff }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need automaticlly select that option so its much easier

```
var value = $('#txt').val();
$('option', 'select').filter(function(){return this.innerText == value;}).prop("selected", true)
```